# Proper way to use std::initializer_list in class constructor

Tags: c++, containers, initializer-list

I'm building a class that has to emulate `vector` (as public interface), and currently i'm building the constructor that accept as parameter an initializer list:

```
template<class T>
class DynamicArray{
public:
    DynamicArray(std::initializer_list<T> l) : size(l.size()), capacity(l.size()), p(std::make_unique<T[]>(l.size())) {
        unsigned int i = 0;
        for(auto& el : l)
            p[i++] = el;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> p;
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int capacity;
};
```

As you can see, for the moment i'm assigning the elements to my array using the `operator=`.. is this the right way or should i use `std::move` or `std::forward` or something else?

Also, checking `vector` for example i can see that it takes the `std::initializer_list` by value, and not by const reference... why?

Comment: `move` or `forward` on elements of initializer list will give you no profit, because items of initializer list are read-only. You can only copy them, as you do it now. By casting T to T&&, you want to invoke move assignment operator, what would modify initializer list item.

Comment: @rafix07 thank you sooooo much... what about the second question? (pass by value, reference, const reference)

Comment: Most cases of passing initializer_list is by value, because it is lightweight proxy class. Pointer to data and its size.

Comment: thanks you so much, please consider to make an answer, i'll be very glad to mark it as correct and upvote it @rafix07